# How can you access a function from a private object that is returning it

Tags: javascript

what i cant understand is how this works,Inside the var Controller
inside the getthedata function i use var input=UICtrl.getinput();
and it works i am curently learning javascript from a course and this makes no sense to me since the UIController is a private Object (or function) that returns something how can access it with just a dot

```js
var BudgetController=(function()
{

})();
var UIController=(function(){
    return {
        getinput: function(){
            console.log(42);
            return {
                type:document.querySelector('.add__type').value,
                description:document.querySelector('.add__description').value,
                value:document.querySelector('.add__value').value
                
            }
            
        }
    }
})();
var Controller=(function(BudgetCtrl,UIctrl){
    var getthedata= function()
    {
        //do the stuff here
        var input=UICtrl.getinput();
        //input();
        console.log('we got dat sweet data');
    };
    document.querySelector('.add__btn').addEventListener('click',getthedata);
    document.addEventListener('keypress',function(e)
    {
        if(e.keyCode==13)
        {
            getthedata();
        }
    });  
})(BudgetController,UIController);
```

everything works fine

Comment: `UIController` has a property `getinput`. You're passing `UIController` to the `Contoller` IIFE as `UIctrl`. Therefore, within that IIFE, you can access the `UIController`'s `getinput` property value by doing `UIctrl.getinput`. Because that value is a function, you would execute it: `UIctrl.getinput()`.

Comment: TLDR: This is a more complex version of passing an object reference as an argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All 3 of your variables are created as immediately invoked functions to, like you said, create a private scope - meaning their variables will not be available for access from outside the scope of the function.

The order that these variables are created is important. By the time you reach `var controller = ...` these two variables already exist: `BudgetController` & `Controller`.

You can see that you are passing `BudgetController` & `Controller` as arguments to your final IIFE. Inside the function you are simply calling the methods made available by the module returned by `UIController`, which is totally fine.

Read up on the [revealing module pattern](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/learning-javascript-design/9781449334840/ch09s03.html) for more information on this pattern.

Comment: The thing that i didnt get was the variables were immediately invoked functions so the getinput ,actually returns to UIControler itself so its like having var UIcontroller={getinput:function(){...}};